# How to take the mean of a netcdf file from the dimensions of the file?

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf4

**Problem:**
I have a netcdf file of data taken every 3 hours however, instead of this being in the time dimension, my netcdf file has another day_period dimension.

**Expected output**
I would like to take the daily mean of the file

The structure of my file is shown below

[NetCDF Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9SPB.png)

I have tried this:

```
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset('2015_2016_SMAPGPH_monmean.nc')
day_mean1 = ds.sel(day_period = range(0,7)).mean()
```

but this gave me just one value of the mean. I would like to have a daily mean value from 2015-2022.

Thank you.

Comment: You can just average over "day_period" dimension with: `day_mean1 = ds.mean(dim='day_period')`.